# How to install from packages in linux ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I know, there are many types packages from which we can install an application in Linux like from .rpm, .deb, .tar.gz etc. Then how many such packages' types are there and please give a list of them  and also please give the way to install from them.

I studied on net also but was unable to understand all of them.

Comment: This might do better on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com), as this is not a programming question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### **How to install packages in *.tar.bz2 form**

To extract the package, you need to open a terminal and:

1. Change the directory to the directory containing the .tar.bz file: `cd /path/to/dir`
2. Extract the bzip2-compressed tarball: `tar xjf FileName.tar.bz2`
3. Change the directory to the newly created directory (use ls to get the directory listing). `cd directory_Where_File_Extracted`
4. Run `./configure`. If you need to have a package installed, you'll be informed here.
5. Run `make` to start compiling
6. Run `sudo make install` to instal

---

### **How to install .deb files from terminal**

1. `sudo dpkg -i packageName.deb`.
2. If dpkg reports an error due to dependency problems, 
   you can run `sudo apt-get install -f` to download the missing dependencies and configure everything.
3. To remove installed packages `sudo dpkg -r packagename`

---

### **How to install .rpm files**

1. To install the package run`sudo rpm -ivh fileName`
2. To upgrade the package run `sudo rpm -Uvh fileName`
3. To remove the package run `sudo rpm -ev PackageName`

Answer (score 1):

Installing a package under Ubuntu is usually as simple as:

```
apt-get install <package>
```

Ubuntu cannot install RPMs, and `tar.gz`s are typically archives of source code to compile, not "packages".

You can search for a package via:

```
apt-cache search <keyword>
```

You can list all installed packaged via:

```
dpkg -l
```

And you can remove one via:

```
apt-get purge <package>
```

(Or `apt-get remove`, if you want to keep configuration data.)

You can also download a `.deb` package and install it manually via:

```
dpkg -i <package>.deb
```

After downloading it to your current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

.deb is from debian, they can be installed using dpkg -i 
a deb is basically a zipfile with 2 archives in them, data.tar.gz and control.tar.gz
data contains all the files and is extracted onto /
control.tar.gz contains a textfile (DEBIAN) which contains all the info of the package, like what name, what version, what to do after install etc.

.rpm is for redhat based systems, it's similar to deb.
rpm's can be installed with Ubuntu by converting them to debs with alien:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RPM/AlienHowto
you can also install them directly by installing the rpm package in ubuntu (sudo apt-get install rpm) and using "rpm -i " this will bypass debian's DPKG so it's not reccommended.

.tgz is from slackware, it only contains the files and is like the .debs usually extracted onto the filesystem.

then there is autopackage (.package) that tries to eliminate the different packaging systems by installing it's own, it will work on all linux distro's but support is limited.
these end on .package you can run these packages as executable and they will install autopackage for you.

then there are SLP packages from stampede linux als lsb packages (linux standard base) from the linux foundation trying to accomplish the same as autopackage.

it's recommended to install all of them using alien on ubuntu except for autopackage.